# Designing a database with a single valued attribute related to multiple entities

Tags: database-design, erd

[image]

Here a **customer** can submit an order for one or many products . so, there is a *one to many* relation between **customer_order** and **customer_ordered_products** entities. Inside **customer_ordered_products** a product is uniquely distinguished by two attributes (`product_category` and `product_id` ). `product_category` is simply name of one of the five entities (**sports_equipments**, **appliances**, **clothes**, **electronics**, **office_supplies** ) representing different products. So, for each entry in  `customer_ordered_products` I can have maximum one `product_id` and one `product_category` . But as only one `product_id` from the five entities can be present in the **customer_ordered_products** entity, so that relation is *many to zero or one*.
The problem is, when I think all of the *zero to one* relation to be zero there would be no `product_id` & when I consider two or more of them to be one(1) then there would be multiple values for a single valued attribute . 
  In this diagram I could use a **product** entity instead of five entities having `product_category` distinguishing different categories .That would solve the problem.  But I do  want to implement this diagram with different entities for different categorized products and solve this problem too.

Comment: Is there a reason for splitting the "product" entity into 5 entities? Why not just 1?

Answer (score 0):

The telling part is where you said "But as only one product_id from the five entities can be present in the customer_ordered_products"

I could fix this by putting a product_category on the customer_order (a "default" if you will) and add a constraint between customer_ordered_products.product_category and customer.product_category that ensures they are the same value.

Another way to do it, if you can, is to remove the product_category from the customer_ordered_products and simple join customer_orders to customer_ordered_products everytime you needed to get that 1 applicable value of product_category.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't add attribute product_category to customer_ordered_products as one order can have multiple products from multiple categories . That's why customer_order & customer_ordered_products are related by one to many .